# apacite not formating URLs correctly

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass[11pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

\author{Cooper Ahrens\\Chanel College\\\emph{3/03/2017}}
\title{Conduction Insulation}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\emph{Title}}
\fancyhead[R]{Cooper Ahrens}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

        \vspace*{5cm}

        \line(1,0){400}\\[1mm]

        \huge{\textbf{Conduction Insulation}}

        \line(1,0){400}\\[1mm]

        \Large{\textbf{Cooper Ahrens\\Chanel College\\\emph{3/03/2017}}}
        \vfill

    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\subsection{Importance of Insulation}

    Sampletext\cite{scott_clarkson_australias_2016}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{physicsbib}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue with the URL is pretty clear. Sorry about the formatting if its wrong I'm new.

Comment: The package `hyphenat` with option `none` is meant to prevent 'any hyphenation throughout the document'....  (I also assume that's why the interword spacing in your bibliography looks so terrible [to me].)

Comment: I removed the package and recompiled but it made no difference to the document whatsoever.

Comment: I'm surprised that it didn't affect hyphenation at a general level. You may find loading a package meant to deal with URLs helpful -- e.g., `url.sty` or `hyperref.sty`.

Comment: I am confused, why are you using apa citations with an IEEE template.

Comment: Try `\raggedright` just before the bibliography to prevent that inter word stretching.

Comment: Off-topic: In the "scott" entry, it looks like you have "smart" apostophe in `Australia's`; change it to a basic (dumb?!) apostrophe and re-run BibTeX.